# Stopping Spring Integration RabbitMQ Inbound Adapter in PCF

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration, cloud-foundry

We have Spring Boot single instance application and it runs in Pivotal Cloud Foundry. This application uses Spring Integration framework to process the messages on RabbitMQ. During maintenance we stop the Inbound Adapter using ControlBus Pattern.

We have to scale the application now we are increasing the number of instances. With ControlBus pattern it is stopping on only one instance. 
What is the best way to stop on all instances?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest is to add a fanout exchange; have each instance bind an `AnonymousQueue` to the fanout. Have one instance send the control message to the fanout (via an amqp oubound-channel-adapter).

Each instance can then use an amqp inbound channel adapter listening on its anonymous queue to send the distributed message to the `<control-bus/>`.